# Как форматировать код в редакторе сайта?

Tags: поддержка, редактор

Вопрос относится только к вставке табуляций в код.

Как я сейчас добавляю код к постам:
Пишу код в своём редакторе, делаю копипаст в редактор сайта, выделяю кнопкой "пример кода".

Либо, копирую эту самую табуляцию и вставляю её сюда в редактор в нужных местах, если пишу на сайте.

```
<div>
<span>Табуляция, где ты?</span>
</div>
```

Я что-то может не знаю, или здесь редактор это не поддерживает?

Comment: Похоже не поддерживает. Я пользуюсь untabify в Emacs

Comment: Как вариант - можно открыть сниппет.....вставить код туда......там нажать "Привести в порядок"..и потом оттуда взять....

Comment: Подскажите, табуляция пропадает после нажатия «пример кода» или сразу после вставки? Какой обозреватель вы используете и какая у вас ОС? Как мне кажется, именно от них зависит, как работает буффер обмена.